# Method Illuminate\Auth\RequestGuard::attempt does not exist. when trying custom authentication via web route

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.7

I have to authenticate users via an external api (something like ldap) and have been trying to realize authentication via a closure request guard as documented here https://laravel.com/docs/master/authentication#closure-request-guards

It works fine if the user logs in correctly, however on auth failure laravel throws the mentioned error `https://laravel.com/docs/master/authentication#closure-request-guards` if the failed attempt is returning `null` from the closure (as it says in the documentation). If it just returns false, laravel doesn't throw an error, however there is no validation feedback.

```php
Auth::viaRequest('ldap', function ($request) {

  $credentials = $request->only('login_id', 'password');
  if ($user = ExternalLDPAAuth::auth()) {
    return $user;
  } else {
    return null;   // laravel throws error

    // return false;   // <- would not throw error, but no validation
  }

}
```

Is there an easier way to do custom authentication?
I don't really understand the documentation about https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/authentication#authenticating-users 
in the end I have to write the guard just like above anyway, right?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't shown the code where you're calling `attempt()`, but you don't need to use that method when authenticating via the request. You use `attempt()` when a user attempts to login with credentials and you need to explicitly attempt to authenticate. With request authentication, Laravel will automatically attempt to authenticate as the request is handled, so your code can simply check to see if `auth()->check()` returns true or not.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. It seems that my understanding of how the authentication drivers and providers work together was wrong. I went and created a custom UserProvider based on EloquentUserProvider to integrate with my third party authentication api.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I decided to customize the EloquentUserProvider instead of the guard. In the end all i needed was additional logic to validate credentials and retrieve a user by credentials in case the user hadn't logged in yet. I.e. checking the normal eloquent logic first and then checking against the external API if nothing was found (also checking for case of changed password).

```php
class CustomUserProvider extends EloquentUserProvider
{
    /**
     * Validate a user against the given credentials.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable  $user
     * @param  array  $credentials
     * @return bool
     */
    public function validateCredentials(UserContract $user, array $credentials)
    {
        // (...)
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve a user by the given credentials.
     *
     * @param  array  $credentials
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable|null
     */
    public function retrieveByCredentials(array $credentials)
    {
        // (...)
    }

}


// config/auth.php
'guards'    => [
        'web' => [
            'driver'   => 'session',
            'provider' => 'custom',
        ],
        // (...)
    ],


// providers/AuthServiceProvider.php

class AuthServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register any authentication / authorization services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        $this->registerPolicies();

        Auth::provider('custom', function ($app, array $config) {
            return new CustomUserProvider($app['hash'], $config['model']);
        });
    }

}
```